# Docker + Kong: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve PostgreSQL server_version_num: connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu-18.04, kong

I'm currently running Docker 19.03.5 and trying to replicate the contents of [this article](https://medium.com/@far3ns/kong-the-microservice-api-gateway-526c4ca0cfa6), but i'm getting the following error in the third step:

**First step:**

```
docker network create kong-net
```

**Second:**

```
docker run -d --name kong-database \
--network=kong-net \
-p 5555:5432 \
-e “POSTGRES_USER=kong” \
-e “POSTGRES_DB=kong” \
postgres:9.6
```

**Third:**

```
docker run --rm \
--network=kong-net \
-e “KONG_DATABASE=postgres” \
-e “KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database” \
kong:latest kong migrations up
```

At this third step, if I use the verbose option, I can see the following error:

```
2019/12/02 15:51:25 [verbose] Kong: 1.4.0
Error: 
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:93: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve 
PostgreSQL server_version_num: connection refused
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'assert'
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:93: in function 'cmd_exec'
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:44>
/usr/local/bin/kong:9: in function 'file_gen'
init_worker_by_lua:48: in function <init_worker_by_lua:46>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
init_worker_by_lua:55: in function <init_worker_by_lua:53>
2019/12/02 15:51:25 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong/kong.conf
2019/12/02 15:51:25 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong.conf
2019/12/02 15:51:25 [verbose] no config file, skip loading
2019/12/02 15:51:25 [verbose] prefix in use: /usr/local/kong
```

My `docker logs -f --tail 10 kong-database`:

```
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-12-02 12:22:46 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and there are no other networks or containers running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The article you're referring is a bit outdated

> Note for Kong < 0.15: with Kong versions below 0.15 (up to 0.14), use
>   the up sub-command instead of bootstrap. Also note that with Kong <
>   0.15, migrations should never be run concurrently; only one Kong node should be performing migrations at a time. This limitation is lifted
>   for Kong 0.15, 1.0, and above.

Reference https://hub.docker.com/_/kong

Kong docs https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker

The instructions below should work

**Create a docker network**

```
docker network create kong-net
```

**Start a PostgreSQL container**

```
docker run -d --name kong-database \
--network=kong-net \
-p 5555:5432 \
-e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
-e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
-e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong" \
postgres:12.2
```

**Prepare your database**

```
docker run --rm \
--network=kong-net \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong" \
kong:2.0.3 kong migrations bootstrap
```

**Start Kong**

```
docker run -d --name kong \
--network=kong-net \
--link kong-database:kong-database \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" \
-p 8000:8000 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-p 8001:8001 \
-p 8444:8444 \
kong
```

Comment: The docs are still using postgres 9.6, which did not work for me. I changed it to 12.2 like you had here and that worked.